# How to get value from this Json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I trying to get  music genres list from my json file loaded with php and and JQuery ajax.

**Here is my json format**

```
[
  "12-bar blues",
  "2 tone",
  "2-step garage",
  "4-beat",
  "50s progression",
  "a cappella",
  "accordion",
  "acid breaks",
  "acid house",
  "acid jazz",
  "acid rock",
  "acid techno",
  "acid trance",
  "acousmatic music",
  "acoustic"
]
```

**JQuery**

```
// Get genres
$("#showgenres").click(function(){

    var genres = $("#genrelist");

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "genres/index",
        method : "GET",
        success: function(data){
           genres.append(data);
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

**PHP**

```
public function index(){

        $file = include APPPATH . "third_party/genres-master/genres.json";
        echo $file;
        //echo json_encode($file);

    }
```

**My HTML file**

```
<h3>Genres:</h3>
<hr>

<div id="genrelist"></div>

<button id="showgenres">Show</button>
```

And Im getting just "raw" json output, I want to get genre values from array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the way you return the json from server:

```
public function index(){
        $file = file_get_contents(APPPATH . "third_party/genres-master/genres.json");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $file;
}
```

You need to create html elements to append.

```
// Get genres
$("#showgenres").click(function(){

    var genres = $("#genrelist");

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "genres/index",
        method : "GET",
        success: function(data){
           var html = "<ul>"
           for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              html += ("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
           }
           html += "</ul>";
           genres.append(html);
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Substituting the Ajax call (I've hosted the json here http://myjson.com/hs8kd):

```js
// Get genres
$("#showgenres").click(function(){

    var genres = $("#genrelist");

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/hs8kd",
        method : "GET",
        success: function(data){
           var html = "<ul>"
           for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              html += ("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
           }
           html += "</ul>";
           genres.append(html);
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Genres:</h3>
<hr>

<div id="genrelist"></div>

<button id="showgenres">Show</button>
```

Comment: This just gives me first letter of each line

Comment: Is the json in string form? Try `data = JSON.parse(data);` before the `for` loop

Comment: Yes I'd tried, but getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 26905"

Comment: Can you share it on pastebin?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try to change the way to return the json from the server.

Comment: I've updated It again. Sorry, I discovered an error: I mispelled `length`.
However, I've added a live snipped to prove that this works. 
Maybe your problem concern the server side part.

Comment: Yes I'm getting correct data output when using url you have pasted, but still getting troubles when fetching from my local server :/

Comment: Please, can you use postman, or any equivalent tool, to call your local server url? It would be great if you can dump the entire response body to pastebin

Comment: It works excellent now, I m getting proper result. Problem was  that I was totaly forgot about to use file_get_content function. Now it is ok, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var htmlData = "";
    $.ajax({
    url: base_url + "genres/index",
    method : "GET",
    success: function(data){
     data=JSON.parse(data);
     $.each(data,function(i,v) {
      htmlData+=v+"<br/>";
      }
       genres.append(htmlData);
    }
});
```

This will display data as:

> 12-bar blues
>
> 2 tone
>
> 2-step garage
>
> 4-beat
>
> 50s progression
>
> a cappella
>
> accordion
>
> acid breaks
>
> acid house
>
> acid jazz
>
> acid rock
>
> acid techno
>
> acid trance
>
> acousmatic music
>
> acoustic

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: base_url + "genres/index",
    method : "GET",
    success: function(data){
        genres.append(data);
    }
});
```